# CSS content-visibility on background-image?

Tags: html, css

I know that CSS content-visibility and contain-intrinsic-size works with IMG tag but does it work with the background-image property?

Does any of those properties have any effect on the code below?

```
<span id="image">

#id{
   height:50px;
   width:100px;
   content-visibility:auto;
   contain-intrinsic-size:50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you can check it using `content-visibility:hidden;`. If the image vanishes then it works and if not then you probably should add `content-visibility: auto` to the parent component.

I stumbled upon the same issue. I have a structure like:

```
<ul>
  <li>
   <button>
     <span classname="bg-image-here"></span>
   </button>
  </li>
  ...
</ul>
```

At first I added `content-visibility` right at   but this seemed to have no effect. Then I moved it to button and the span disappeared